# join 3 tables in mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have 3 tables in my database :-

1. tbl_roles(role_id,role_name);
2. tbl_users(id,role_id,username,email,password);
3. tbl_tickets_replies(id,ticket_id,user_id,role_id,comments)

`role_id, id, id` are primary keys of corresponding tables.
i need :-

1. username from tbl_users.
2. role_name from tbl_roles.
3. comments from tbl_tickets

where `ticket_id` from `tbl_tickets_replies` = `$ticket_id` coming as a parameter.

My Model Function is :-

```
function fetch_comments($ticket_id){
        $this->db->select('tbl_tickets_replies.comments,tbl_users.username,tbl_roles.role_name');
        $this->db->where('tbl_tickets_replies.ticket_id',$ticket_id);
        $this->db->from('tbl_tickets_replies');
        $this->db->join('tbl_users','tbl_users.id = tbl_tickets_replies.user_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_roles','tbl_roles.role_id=tbl_tickets_replies.role_id');
        $comments = $this->db->get('tbl_tickets_replies');
        return $comments;
     }
```

this is showing database error i.e., I am doing wrong query.
I want to ask how can I join three tables to fetch data from 3 different tables

This error is showing :-

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_tickets_replies'
>
> SELECT `tbl_tickets_replies`.`comments`, `tbl_users`.`username`,
>   `tbl_roles`.`role_name` FROM (`tbl_tickets_replies`,
>   `tbl_tickets_replies`) JOIN `tbl_users` ON `tbl_users`.`id` =
>   `tbl_tickets_replies`.`user_id` JOIN `tbl_roles` ON
>   `tbl_roles`.`role_id`=`tbl_tickets_replies`.`role_id` WHERE
>   `tbl_tickets_replies`.`ticket_id` = '6'
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\local.helpdesk.com\bonfire\codeigniter\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330`

Comment: Remove the `from` clause or remove the table from $this->db->get(). You don't need both. What error do you get?

Comment: You didn't remove `$this->db->from` or did: `$this->db->get();`

Comment: thanks yan solved by removing $this->db->from()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to `tbl_tickets_replies` twice.
Try this:

```
function fetch_comments($ticket_id){
    $this->db->select('tbl_tickets_replies.comments, 
           tbl_users.username,tbl_roles.role_name');
    $this->db->where('tbl_tickets_replies.ticket_id',$ticket_id);
    $this->db->join('tbl_users','tbl_users.id = tbl_tickets_replies.user_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_roles','tbl_roles.role_id=tbl_tickets_replies.role_id');
    return $this->db->get('tbl_tickets_replies');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For complex queries, i prefer using the plain SQL as follows.

```
$sql = "SELECT....";
$q = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Btw, try removing the table name from db->get function

```
$comments = $this->db->get(); //change this
```

Comment: using that active records function, queries can be made simple

Comment: If you should build your query dinamically then the raw sql is difficult (or impossible).

Answer (score 0):

Join with condition.

```
$this->db->select('*'); $this->db->from('articles');
$this->db->join('category', 'category.id = articles.id');
$this->db->where(array('category.id' => 10)); $query =
$this->db->get();
```