# Joining on CodeIgniter tables in this query multi tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to join 1 to 3 tables in CodeIgniter, how can I do that?

In this query I have joined only one table how I can I join my 3rd, 4th table

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table1', 'table1.dep_id = table2.dep_id', 'table1.status= 1');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->order_by("expiredate", "desc");
    
    return $this->db->get()->result();
```

my table structure as follow

Table1

```
t1_id
t1_name
t2_id
t3_id
t4_id
```

Table2

```
t2_id
t2_name
```

Table3

```
t3_id
t3_name
```

Table4

```
t4_id
t4_name
```

How can I join my 3rd and 4th

Comment: What about another `join` call?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524752/join-3-tables-in-mysql-codeigniter

Comment: didn't work with this

Comment: @rafiq explain in brief or give your table structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this I think its work

```
$this->db->select('table1.*,table2.t2_name,table3.t3_name,table4.t4_name');
$this->db->from('table1','table2','table3','table4');

$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.t2_id= table2.t2_id');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table1.t3_id= table3.t3_id');
$this->db->join('table4', 'table1.t4_id= table4.t4_id');

return $this->db->get()->result();
```

OR you can use SQL query to get result....

```
$this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

Comment: no not working(just i want to joing 1 table to 3 tables when my first table has relation ship with other 3  @RS Sisodia

Answer (score 1):

Try symultaneous join like

```
$this->db->join('table1', 'table1.t2_id = table2.t2_id', 'table1.status= 1');
```

and in meanwhile you need to join any one of table1 ,tabl2 to join with table3 or 4 like

```
$this->db->join('table3', 'table1.t3_id = table3.t3_id');
$this->db->join('table4', 'table1.t4_id = table4.t3_id');
```

and moreover you need to select table like

```
$this->db->select('table1.*,table2.*,..');
```

like this way and another thing is if any columns are same for table1 and table2 then you need to select as **alias** like

```
$this->db->select('table1.id as tab1id,table2.id as tab2id');
```

in above table1,2 are same column names "id"

Comment: query is on my qustion first part i have joined tow table and working fine but the 3rd one is not working if i add another join then noting get's display